# How to display values that belong _to an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am practicing rails by developing a band application where Venues have many events and bands and those events and bands belong to the Venues.

I have foreign keys set up, I am just a little confused on how to display attributes of the venues controller within the Events index.html.erb

I want to show which specific Venue my event belongs to and vice versa.

This is my events controller

```
 class EventsController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        @events = Event.all
        #should I store my venues in the index to show its values?
        @venues = Venue.where(params[:id])
    end

    def edit 
        @events = Event.find(params[:id])
        puts @events.inspect
    end

    def update 
        @events = Event.find(params[:id])
        @events.update_attributes(name: params[:event][:name], date: params[:event][:date], alcohol_served: params[:event][:alcohol_served], venue_id: params[:event][:venue_id], band_id: params[:event][:band_id])
        redirect_to action: 'index'
    end

    def destroy
        @events=Event.find(params[:id])
        @events.destroy
        redirect_to action: 'index'
    end

    def new 
        @Events = Event.new
    end

    def create
        @Events = Event.create(name: params[:event][:name], date: params[:event][:date], alcohol_served: params[:event][:alcohol_served], venue_id: params[:event][:venue_id], band_id: params[:event][:band_id])
        @Events.save
        redirect_to action: 'index'
    end


end
```

Disregard some of my redirects they are only for test purposes

Here are my models

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events
    has_many :bands, through: :events
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :band 
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events
end
```

Comment: can you share your event, band and venues models?

Comment: @StephanePaquet I added them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Venue and want to know all the events taking place at this Venue: `@events = Event.find_by(:venue_id venue.id)`

If you have an event and want to find the venue

```
venue_id = Event.select(:venue_id).find(params[:id])
@venue = Venue.find(venue_id)
```

You can replace in `params[:id]` by `event.id` depending on the use case.

Comment: that would be in the def index within the controller and such? I didn't know I could do that, thanks!

Comment: Yes in the controller. ActionRecord is offering an abstraction layer to your database. In this case the fact that a venue has many events means that in the event migration you have an id pointing back to the venue and by convention this is venue_id

Comment: Would this be the same case if I was in my bands controller and wanted to display the event?

Comment: It should. You can also add nested_attributes to create more "user friendly" relations, see Rails user's guide for more information about this.